# SqlException: A instrução INSERT conflitou com a restrição do FOREIGN KEY

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Possuo um relacionamento 1-n de empresa-funcionario.

Usei as migrations do entity pra criar as tabelas com base no meus modelos. Verifiquei no banco de dados e as tabelas foram criadas com suas respectivas PK e FK.

Porém, quando meu método .SaveChangesAsync(); é chamado, é retornado erro de conflito no bd com a foreign key.

**Esse é meu método:**

```
// POST api/funcionario
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Funcionario>> cadastraFuncionario(Funcionario funcionario)
{
    _context.Funcionario.Add(funcionario);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return NoContent();
}
```

**Meu funcionario model:**

```
public class Funcionario
{
    public int FuncionarioId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Cargo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> Salario { get; set; }
    //Foreign Key
    public int EmpresaId { get; set; }
    public Empresa Empresas { get; set; }
}
```

**Minha empresa model:**

```
 public class Empresa
    {
        public int EmpresaId { get; set;}
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Cep { get; set; }
        public string Logradouro { get; set; }
        public string Complemento { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Numero { get; set; }
        public string Bairro { get; set; }
        public string Localidade { get; set; }
        public string UF { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Unidade { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> IBGE { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> GIA { get; set; }
        public string Telefone{get;set;}
        public ICollection<Funcionario> Funcionarios { get; set; }
    }
```

No meu BD possui uma Empresa cujo id é 1.

Tento fazer essa requisição através do postman:

**POST**

```
{
    "empresaId": 1,
    "nome": "Teste",
    "cargo": "Teste",
    "salario": 10850
}
```

Mas recebo:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

> SqlException: A instrução INSERT conflitou com a restrição do FOREIGN
>   KEY "FK_Funcionario_Empresa_EmpresaId". O conflito ocorreu no banco de
>   dados "Crud", tabela "dbo.Empresa", column 'EmpresaId'. A
>   instrução foi finalizada.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.b__122_0(Task
>   result)
>
> DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See
>   the inner exception for details.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection
>   connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: Conseguiu solucionar?

Comment: @LP.Gonçalves provavelmente sim, mas faz tanto tempo que eu não me recordo mais

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copiei as suas classes e habilitei o migrations. Fiz o exemplo abaixo e funcionou. Só deu erro quando não é atribuido valor na propriedade `EmpresaId` do `Funcionario`.

**Deu certo desta forma:**

```
  public class CrudContext : DbContext
{
    public CrudContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Funcionario> Funcionarios { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Empresa> Empresas { get; set; }

}

public void Add()
    {
        try
        {
            using (CrudContext context = new CrudContext())
            {
                var empresa = new Empresa
                {
                    EmpresaId = 1,
                    Nome = "Empresa 3",
                    Bairro = "Teste",
                    Cep = "000000",
                    UF = "PR",
                    Logradouro = "Rua aaaaa",
                    Complemento = "aaaa",
                    Localidade = "CTBA",
                    GIA = 1,
                    IBGE = 1,
                    Numero = 10,
                    Telefone = "0000",
                    Unidade = 2
                };

                context.Empresas.Add(empresa);
                context.SaveChanges();

                // Deu certo
                var funcionario = new Funcionario { EmpresaId = 1, FuncionarioId = 2, Nome = "Teste", Cargo = "Teste", Salario = 10 };

                // Deu erro se nao informar o EmpresaId
                //var funcionario = new Funcionario { FuncionarioId = 3, Nome = "Teste", Cargo = "Teste", Salario = 10 };

                context.Funcionarios.Add(funcionario);
                context.SaveChangesAsync().Wait();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```